# how to tabulate reference category

Tags: stata, frequency

i've got a qualitative variable "profession" which can assume 5 different values which are: worker, office worker, teacher, employee management, manager.
I choosed worker as the reference category so i created 4 different dummy variables for the remaining categories.

Using Stata i can see frequency percentage associated with the sex variable typing "tabulate sex teacher, row col" for each created dummy variable.

How can i do the same for the reference category worker(which doesn't have a dummy variable associated)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to handle the "worker dummy" different to the other dummies. Typing `tabulate workerdummy, row col` gives you what you want: The gender distribution for workers against the gender distribution of all non-workers.

```
// Setup dataset
clear
input str20 profession str20 sex
"Worker" "Female"
"Worker" "Female"
"Worker" "Female"
"Worker" "Male"
"Office Worker" "Male"
"Office Worker" "Male"
"Office Worker" "Female"
"Teacher" "Female"
"Teacher" "Female"
"Teacher" "Female"
"Teacher" "Female"
"Teacher" "Female"
"Teacher" "Female"
"Teacher" "Male"
"Teacher" "Male"
"Employee Management" "Male"
"Employee Management" "Male"
"Employee Management" "Male"
"Manager" "Male"
"Manager" "Male"
"Manager" "Female"
"Manager" "Female"
"Manager" "Female"
"Manager" "Female"
"Manager" "Female"
end

//Define dummies
tabulate profession, gen(profdum)

//Show two-way table
tabulate profdum5 sex, row col
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roberto! This tip really helped me!The problem was I did all different dummies manually one by one, but this way is much more quick and usefull!! Thanks a lot!!